# numpy array assignment in debug mode

Tags: numpy, debugging, variable-assignment

I have a very strange problem in Python 3.6.4 and Numpy 1.14.1. I assign in debugger mode a Numpy array to the variable "a" (does not work) and works when I use another variable, for example, "x". I have realized that the assignment works from "d". Why is that? This issue happens in debug mode. Thank you in advance for any clue. Please see the console outputs. 
Karlos

```
(Pdb) a = np.array([[1,2], [2,3]])
(Pdb) a
(Pdb) x = np.array([[1,2], [2,3]])
(Pdb) x
array([[1, 2],
       [2, 3]])
(Pdb) b = np.array([[1, 6]])
*** The specified object '= np.array([[1' is not a function or was not found along sys.path.
(Pdb) x = np.array([[1, 6]])
(Pdb) x
array([[1, 6]])
(Pdb) type(a)
*** NameError: name 'a' is not defined
(Pdb) type(x)
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to say `p a` to print `a`.  Some things are debugger keywords, and it is simply a quirk of `pdb` that it lets you print variables whose names happen not to collide with any debugger command.  Some names, like `b`, are so commonly used in the debugger itself that it does not think you mean to refer to a variable.  You can use the `!` command to say "Execute the following Python code," like this:

```
(Pdb) ! a = np.array([[1,2], [2,3]])
(Pdb) p a
```

Here, the debugger commands `!` (execute) and `p` (print) are used explicitly, instead of asking `pdb` to guess which `a` you meant (in which case it assumes you meant to invoke its built-in `args` command).